# How to find the source of file that copied to USB drive

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, clipboard, copy-paste

I've an MFC application to track the file operations in the USB device, It works fine and providing right reports. it uses **`ReadDirectoryChangesW`** API. when I copy a file to USB drive it shows as the file is created **but I want to know the source path of the file that copied to the USB**.
Is there is any way to find it please share

Comment: From the user-side, you can't, unless you track ALL file openings (and bear in mind that not all files created on a device must be opened, or be currently open when the copy is made - imagine a program that reads a file, closes it, then sleeps for two minutes, then writes the file out to the USB device - not considering programs that actually generate the data in themselves). If you believe the copy is made via CopyFile, then perhaps you can intercept that via Detours or something, but there's no guarantee of this.

Comment: Note that someone REALLY devious could do the following: Create a program that allocates "shared memory", then create another program that loads a file into that shared memory, and a third that writes it to the USB device. Assuming someone that has the ability to program and understands how your program is seeing files. This would be very hard to "spot".

Comment: `IFileOperation` has `IFileOperationProgressSink` but that only informs you about the progrss of your _own_ copy action.

Comment: @MSalters Do you know how to implements it in cpp?

Comment: @MarshalSebastian: Yes, but there's a reason I commented - it's **not** an answer.

Comment: @MSalters That's ok if you share it let me check there is any possibility with it

Comment: See MSDN example for `IFileOperation::CopyItem`, last argument is `IFileOperationProgressSink`. The example also shows why it's not an answer - you already _know_ the source.